# Ploting data points by omitting the lines Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

how do I plot only the data points by omitting the lines with Python Python/matplotlib.

Here is my example code so far:

```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import pandas as pd

  df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,-3,3,5,7,-1],
                   'y' : [2.6,3.4,3.25,2.8,1.75,1.34,-3.345]})
  df.plot(x='x', y='y')
  plt.grid(True)
  plt.show()
```

All helpfull comments are appericated.

so far I tried although

```
df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y')
```

but for my real applications, there seems to be a problem, that's why I was wondering if there exists another way to plot the data points.

As someone pointed out, I should say something about the issue. So I use df = pd.read_csv(...) to get my data. And for some reason df.plot.scatter (...) did not work. I always got " not in index" error. So When I tried any of the solutions mentioned here, I did not get the same Problem. 
To be frank I have no Idea why there was a problem in the first place. Still, I wanted to least mention the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `kind='scatter'` as a paramater in pandas plot as shown in your code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,-3,3,5,7,-1],
                   'y' : [2.6,3.4,3.25,2.8,1.75,1.34,-3.345]})
df.plot(x='x', y='y', kind='scatter')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, everyone for all the good answers and they are working fine. Much appreciated

Answer (score 14):

You can use parameters `marker` and `linestyle` in `plt.plot`. You can experiment with marker, but if you want to omit lines, `linestyle='none'` is crucial here.

```
plt.plot(df.x, df.y, marker='.', linestyle='none')
```

Comment: Thanks to you too.

Comment: Sure, with my original Data I couldn't use scatter, I always got "not in index". I read a csv file via python panda. Now with the answers, it worked. I am not sure why  df.plot.scatter did not worked in my case.

Comment: @Alexander - edited, though I think it was pretty self-explanatory anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

or replace last three lines

```
df.plot(x='x', y='y')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

by:

```
plt.scatter(x=df.x.tolist(), y=df.y.tolist())
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Lastly but not least you too.

Answer (score 0):

At least as of today, `df.plot()` accepts `matplotlib.plot` arguments as keyword arguments. Hence you can simply do `df.plot(linestyle='none',marker='.') to get the desired behaviour.

Happy Coding!